# Comparing elements from different dataframes nested in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have around 80 similarly structured csv files (same columns names and same rows number) from which I want to obtain the maximum value in each cell from the whole set of files.
My idea for now was to load them in a list and then compare, but I'm having problems retrieving the cell values from the nested dataframes.
This is the code to load the csv in a list of dataframes:

```
import glob
allFiles = glob.glob("./*.txt")
results = [None]*len(allFiles)
i=0
for file_ in allFiles:
    results[i] = pd.read_csv(file_, sep = "\t")
    i=i+1
```

And, as an example, let's try to compare these two files files:

```
a.txt
t   a   b
0   1   2
1   3   4
2   5   6

b.txt
t   a   b
0   1   3
1   0   2
2   7   9
```

Each elements in the results list is a dataframe:

```
>> results[i].info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 1 columns):
t   a   b    3 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
```

I want to find the maximum value of the two dataframes in each cell and have as a final output another dataframe with, in each position, the maximum value corresponding to that position, which in this case would result in :

```
t   a   b
0   1   3
1   3   4
2   7   9
```

How can I manage to do it? 
Or maybe there is a better way to set up the whole problem?
Thanks

Comment: Without a [MCVE] it is unclear what you're asking. The code you posted seems to be completely irrelevant for the actual question (comparing elements from different dataframes). Give us some sample dataframes and the output you want.

Comment: I haven't managed to write any code to compare since I haven't been able to access the elements in the listed dataframes. Now I've added the two csv files that  I'm using as an example. Hopefully now it's more clear

Comment: Thanks for the sample dataframes. "I cannot manage to access the elements inside" is still vague. What values do you want to access, and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: I want to obtain, for each cell in the dataframe, the maximum value considering all the dataframes present in the list

Comment: Cool, now we're having an answerable question!

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the maximum of all the `t` columns, all the `a` columns and all the `b` columns, right?

Comment: No, I want the maximum for each position so like max(a.t[0],b.t[0]), max(a.t[1],b.t[1]),max(a.a[0],b.a[0]), etc.. This maximum function has to consider all the dataframes in the list and I'd like to have a database with all the maximums as the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one big DataFrame with `MultiIndex` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
allFiles = glob.glob("./*.txt")
results = [pd.read_csv(file_, sep = "\t") for file_ in allFiles]

names = [os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0] for f in allFiles]
df = pd.concat(results, keys=names)
print (df)
     t   a   b
a 0  0   1   2
  1  1   3   4
  2  2   5   6
b 0  0   1   3
  1  1   0   2
  2  2   7   9
```

And then if need max values per each DataFrame:

```
max_val = df.max(level=0)
print (max_val)
   t   a   b
a  2   5   6
b  2   7   9

max_val = df.max(level=1)
print (max_val)
   t   a   b
0  0   1   3
1  1   3   4
2  2   7   9
```